# How do I import a Python package from the top level (from FastAPI docs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am working through the "[Bigger Applications - Multiple Files](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/)" section of the FastAPI docs. This describes a package structure with a top-level directory called `app`, a `main.py` and `__init__.py` in that directory, and then two subdirectories named `routers` and `internal` each with their own `__init__.py` and source files.

In `main.py` (again, from the top level, this is `app/main.py`), they describe adding the line: `from app.routers import items`

However, this does not work for me, even in the simplest example:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── foo
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── bar.py
```

Both `__init__.py` files are empty. `main.py` is one line:

`from app.foo import bar`

`foo/bar.py` is:

```
def baz():
    print("hi")
```

That's it. As simple as it gets, while still following the model described in the FastAPI docs. However it fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/src/app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app.foo import bar
```

Similarly, they describe using relative imports like `from .internal import admin`. This too does not work.

What gives? I can find similar patterns in many projects and documents, but I can't figure out what I am missing in making this work. Yes, I could put `main.py` a level up and everything else in a subdirectory. But that's adding clutter, and based on the docs it seems like this is something that should work (I realize this is not a FastAPI-specific problem, it's just that their docs have a clear example). Similarly, I have found answers that talk about changing PYTHONPATH, but I have seen no evidence that other projects using this pattern do that. There must be something I am missing.

I am using Python 3.9.5, but I've tried it with 3.6.x also.

Comment: From which directory are you running the application from? Where are you at when you are running `uvicorn main:app`?

Comment: @AndreFeijo running it from the directory that contains the `main.py` file. Otherwise, I don't think `main:app` will resolve.